# Replacement in file using bash

Tags: shell-script, csh

I'm trying to translate (a pretty lengthy) script from csh to bash. It takes a 'Makefile' and performs the commands:

```
cpp_begin_line=`grep -n cpp_flags Makefile | sed 's/:/ /' `
cpp_end_line=`grep -n lioapi Makefile | sed 's/:/ /' `
```

Here the value of **cpp_begin_line** is:

```
48  cpp_flags = \
71  CPP_FLAGS   = $(cpp_flags)
```

and the value of **cpp_end_line** is:

```
73  IOAPI  = -L$(LIB)/ioapi/lib -lioapi
```

These numbers come from lines 48, 71, and 73 in the Makefile. Then, the script tries to perform the operations

```
diff=1+$cpp_end-$cpp_begin
head -n $cpp_end Makefile | tail -n $diff | sed 's/-Dparallel/-Dparallel -Dtwoway/'  >> Makefile.twoway
```

that fail because **diff** is equal to

```
  1+73  IOAPI  = -L$(LIB)/ioapi/lib -lioapi[1]-1-48  cpp_flags = \
71  CPP_FLAGS   = $(cpp_flags)[1]
```

Here, I was expecting that **diff** would become some numerical difference to be used by tail.

Comment: `diff=1+$cpp_end-$cpp_begin` doesn't look like either csh or bash arithmetic. Are you sure `sed 's/:/ /'` shouldn't have been `sed 's/:.*//'` ?

Comment: It's not my original script so I'm unsure why the developer did some things in a certain way. Your suggestion makes things a lot better as it eliminates some of the verbosity. For example, cpp_begin_line is 48 71 (in new line) and cpp_end_line is simply 73. As far as the declaration of diff, that is how it was in the original csh script (supposedly it works).